# issue taking a perl API call that is in JSON

Tags: java, perl, subdomain

hello I am having an issue taking a perl API call that is in JSON i want to get all subdomains from this link

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Response;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON qw( decode_json encode_json );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");

my $url = "https://www.threatcrowd.org/searchApi/v2/domain/report/?domain=fb.com";

my $request = $ua->get($url);
my $response = $request->content;

my $decoded = decode_json($response);

print $decoded->{'subdomains'};
```

and if run this script get this

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>1.pl
ARRAY(0x625c868
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is truly a simple array reference (you can check by using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)), you need to iterate over the list and print each element/item:

```
for my $element (@{ $decoded->{'subdomains'} }){
    print "$element\n";
}
```

That `@{}` syntax is a dereference operator. It dereferences the array reference held in the variable within its braces.

See the [Using References](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) section in the [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) documentation for more information.